# deploying image in kubernetes cluster getting CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-cluster

I am using kubernetes cluster to deploy an image using kubectl create -f dummy.yaml . my image is public in docker hub, the size of the image is 1.3 GB. 
the image pull successfully but it is not running it is " CrashLoopBackOff".
when  i run creation deployment command "kubectl create -f dummy.yaml" i got:

```
 Name                         READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
 dummy-ser-5459bf444d-9b7sz   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   118        10h
```

I tried to used
`command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]` in my yaml file, it is work with image size 700 MB but it show CrashLoopBackOff when i use it with other image 1.3 GB, it seems the container after pulling cannot run because the image successful pulled.

The describe pods show :

```
Events:
Type     Reason                 Age                From               Message
----     ------                 ----               ----               -------
Normal   Scheduled              12m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned dummy-ser-779                                 7db4cd4-djqdz to node02
Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  12m                kubelet, node02    MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for vol                                 ume "default-token-8p9lq"
Normal   Created                1m (x4 over 2m)    kubelet, node02    Created container
Normal   Started                1m (x4 over 2m)    kubelet, node02    Started container
Warning  BackOff                53s (x8 over 2m)   kubelet, node02    Back-off restarting failed containe                                 r
Normal   Pulling                41s (x5 over 12m)  kubelet, node02    pulling image "xxx/dummyenc:ba                                 ni"
Normal   Pulled                 40s (x5 over 2m)   kubelet, node02    Successfully pulled image "xxx
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: If you’re getting `CrashLoopBackOff` then the image successfully pulled and it’s not starting up (or exiting).  Without knowing more details of the image (like its Dockerfile and the Kubernetes Deployment spec) or the `kubectl logs` output of the failing pod it’s going to be really hard to say more.

Comment: @DavidMaze I add the event logs that i got from describe pods commad

Comment: `kubectl logs --previous xxx` on that pod

Comment: @HoMan kubectl logs --previous xxx shows "the server doesn't have a resource type "xxx" "

Comment: .. you should put in the pod name. e.g. `kubectl logs --previous dummy-ser-5459bf444d-9b7sz`

Comment: and add your `dummy.yaml` please

Comment: @Nick Rak..Fixed, the problem was the image not support ARM7 because I built the image in Ubuntu 64.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem. I got this error because the image was not compatible with the hardware that I tried to run on (ARM7)RPi. I create the image on ubuntu 64bit using docker build for Dockerfile so that image cannot run on Raspberry pi.